# What are the historical reasons that Haskell's [] is named List and not Stack

Tags: list, haskell, functional-programming, stack

The behavior of Haskel's list is much better characterized as a stack (`empty=[]`, `isEmpty=isEmpty`, `top=head`, `pop= tail`, `push=(:)`) than a  list.

Common immutable list operations (`length`, `get`) are *O(n)* and defined using the previous mentioned operations.

What are the historical reasons to name this type a List and not a Stack?

Comment: For me a Stack is more the "interface": you can implement a stack with an array, linked list, etc. The Haskell list, is a linked list, which is a concrete datastructure. So in that perspective "list" says more what it *is*, whereas "Stack" more says what it *does*. But of course it's all a matter of "what's in a name?" and "how do you define things".

Comment: If you were starting from scratch, what naming would you think better reflect the type constructed?:
`Stack a = Empty | Cons a (Stack a)`
or
`List a = Empty | Cons a (List a)`

Comment: I would go for `List`. But as said before, it is all a matter on what you think a list/stack is. If I look on wikipedia a stack seems to be described as an *abstract* data type. So there are several *ways* to implement it. Now a list is also an *abstract* data type. So perhaps a more rigorous form would be `LinkedList`. But of course it is not very convenient to work with such names. This comment is of course not an answer as to what the historical reasons were (I don't know).

Comment: Futhermore, Wikipedia, when describing abstract definition of List, says **These axioms are equivalent to those of the abstract stack data type.**. So, in some point in history (Lisp creation, maybe), someone chose to name it List instead of Stack

Comment: I guess it comes from "linked list" and "Lisp cons-lists". Also, "stack" sounds weird in most contexts. E.g. "read the numbers from file into a stack, then compute the sum of the stack, finally compute the product of the stack" seems to imply 0) that every element of the file is pushed, 1) that the sum is computed from the last element to the first, 2) that the stack is so consumed in the process, 3) that the product can no longer be computed since the stack is gone. Also, I'd expect a `map` operation on a stack to reverse it, or to require two passes.

Comment: I agree with you that "stack" sounds weird, but that is due to we are used to think that stacks are mutable data structures different from our loved list. If you implement your example, you will deconstruct your list in the very same way a stack works.

Comment: @Nykros: not entirely. Usually the way I have been taught what a stack is, is that the *top* is accessible, but the underlying parts are not necessarily accessible (without popping the top). So in order to calculate the sum, you should consume the top. The "interface" of a stack is usually push/pop(/peek). With these functions you cannot both calculate an aggregate of the stack and keeping it intact. Of course you can use a second stack to buffer the elements and then "restore" the original stack.

Comment: Sorry @WillemVanOnsem, but I'm unable to find the difference between a sum of list and a sum of a stack:

`sumList xs = if (isEmpty xs) then 0 else head xs + sumList (tail xs)`
or 
`sumStack st = if (isEmptyS st) then 0 else (top st) + sumStack (top st)`

Quoting wikipedia: **In many implementations, a stack has more operations than "push" and "pop". An example is "top of stack", or "peek", which observes the top-most element without removing it from the stack. Since this can be done with a "pop" and a "push" with the same data, it is not essential**

Comment: @Nykros: yes peek is indeed a simple push and pop and requires *O(1)* memory. But obtaining the *i*-th element cannot be done without constructing an additional collection (given you only have push/pop/peek) to store at least *O(i)* elements.

The reaon why your `sumStack` works is of course because data structure are immutable in Haskell. But by using a Stack like in C++/Java you cannot do that.

Comment: I narrowed the scope of my question from the very begining to Haskell's (Miranda, KRC, Gofer) list because this statement is not true in mutable data structures.

If Haskell's list are really stacks, why they chose to call them list?

I'm almost sure it was more fancy to call them lists and not stacks, but I want to know for sure.

Anyway, the community is supporting your view @WillemVanOnsem. I'm been downvoted and your comments are upvoted.

Comment: @Nykros: look I did not downvoted you (and furthermore I'm *not* saying that your arguments are worthless/don't make any sense) ;). It is also good to sometimes think about these thinks. It was only an opinion why a computer scientist would probably name it list and not stack.

Comment: Thank you, you are very kind.

Comment: For the historical reasons specifically I think @chi is exactly right: they are lists because they are the direct equivalent to Lisp cons-lists. Why are they called lists in Lisp? 1) It isn't much younger than concept of stack itself, and I wouldn't be surprised if "immutable stack" would be considered a contradiction at the time; 2) Lisp code is itself famously represented as nested lists, but I don't think thinking of it as a stack is useful.

Comment: Beyond this, laziness adds another problem: you _don't_ need to already have a "stack" before "pushing" something on it.

Comment: I have been reading the John McCarthy 1960' paper [link](http://www-formal.stanford.edu/jmc/recursive.pdf) and he clearly meant to use linked list in the IBM 704 LISP implementation. 

It is easy to say now "hey! Haskel's lists behaves like a (inmutable) stacks!" having the advantage of almost 60 years of development in computer science. 

If any of the commenters would elaborate an answer I will be glad to accept it.

I have enjoyed your input very much.